# Create a new column based on Grouping of similar values in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Hi I have an event data frame with datetimes and event ids and sensor ids. I would like to group events that happen within one hour per sensor and if possible tag them with the group count.
Original Data Frame

```
         sensor_id  event_id   time  
    0    A         e1            2017-02-14 05:30:00      
    1    A         e2            2017-02-14 05:45:00 
    2    A         e3            2017-02-14 08:30:00 
    3    B         e3            2017-02-14 05:20:00 
    4    B         e4            2017-02-14 05:30:00 
    5    B         e6            2017-02-14 05:45:00 
    6    C         e1            2017-02-14 05:30:00 
    7    C         e3            2017-02-14 07:30:00 
    8    C         e7            2017-02-14 09:35:00
```

Desired Result:

```
         sensor_id  event_id      time                  group 
    0    A         e1            2017-02-14 05:30:00      1
    1    A         e2            2017-02-14 05:45:00      1
    2    A         e3            2017-02-14 08:30:00      2
    3    B         e3            2017-02-14 05:20:00      1
    4    B         e4            2017-02-14 05:30:00      1
    5    B         e6            2017-02-14 05:45:00      1
    6    C         e1            2017-02-14 05:30:00      1
    7    C         e3            2017-02-14 07:30:00      2
    8    C         e7            2017-02-14 09:35:00      3
```

I understand that I should group by user, event and then, time using timdelta of 1 hour but I have no clue how to do the rest.  Any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pd.TimeGrouper` + `ngroup` to group by time frequency.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df['group'] = df.set_index('time').groupby(['sensor_id', 
                    pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1H')], sort=False).ngroup().values
```

So far, we have what we want, but we'll need to reset the `group` value for each `sensor_id`, so another `groupby` call is in order.

```
df['group'] = df.groupby('sensor_id').group.apply(lambda x: x - x.min() + 1)

df

  sensor_id event_id                time  group
0         A       e1 2017-02-14 05:30:00      1
1         A       e2 2017-02-14 05:45:00      1
2         A       e3 2017-02-14 08:30:00      2
3         B       e3 2017-02-14 05:20:00      1
4         B       e4 2017-02-14 05:30:00      1
5         B       e6 2017-02-14 05:45:00      1
6         C       e1 2017-02-14 05:30:00      1
7         C       e3 2017-02-14 07:30:00      2
8         C       e7 2017-02-14 09:35:00      3
```

Comment: wouldn't that ignore sensor ids though? I need it per sensor id.

Comment: Since you deleted the post I was very quick to find a solution. But you came back

Comment: Yeah I thought ngroup would be enough but it wont reset for every group so had to go for nested group.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to go for dual groupby (Hope sensor_id is sorted if not we need to sorted them first) i.e

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('sensor_id').apply( lambda x : x.groupby(x['time'].dt.hour).ngroup()+1).values
```

Output :

```
  sensor_id event_id                time  new
0         A       e1 2017-02-14 05:30:00    1
1         A       e2 2017-02-14 05:45:00    1
2         A       e3 2017-02-14 08:30:00    2
3         B       e3 2017-02-14 05:20:00    1
4         B       e4 2017-02-14 05:30:00    1
5         B       e6 2017-02-14 05:45:00    1
6         C       e1 2017-02-14 05:30:00    1
7         C       e3 2017-02-14 07:30:00    2
8         C       e7 2017-02-14 09:35:00    3
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this seems like something that might work.. why do you think sorting of sensor_id is necessary? wouldn't groupby do it anyways?

Comment: It's because Im getting .values at the end so assignment is not based on sorting so.

Comment: I upvoted your solution however, for some reason it fails to work on larger data sets so I chose the one by coldspeed

Comment: Maybe its because `x['time'].dt.hour` Try the same solution with `pd.TimeGrouper(freq='1H')` inside apply. Hope it helps